# Best Practices For Async-Storage React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, asyncstorage

I am looking for advice or documentation on the best practices for react native's `async-storage`.

Two specific questions I have are:

- Is it poor design to get and set data once a day?
- Does it ever expire?

The data I would be setting/ getting daily is minimal if that matters at all. I would prefer to not use the DB as it can cut down on costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you're setting does not need to be persisted beyond the app, then there really is no problem with getting and setting once a day. would definitely save you costs on using a database for just that.

And no, I don't think it ever expires.